# Python request JSON intermittent Type Error

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm making a lot of requests to an API using Python (3.5) in Jupyter Notebooks.
The code looks like this:

```
...
r = requests.post(url=url, json=json, headers=headers)
bar = r.json()["foo"]["bar"]
...
```

The issue I encounter is that it works correctly most of the time, but seems to randomly throw a Type Error: "String Indices must be Integers" on the second line above.
One might deduce that it means the returned value is a simple string/not a JSON object and therefore cannot be accessed with a key, but that's not the case: if I restart with the exact same request (same url, same JSON query, same header), the error is not thrown!

It just seems to happen randomly: sometimes it works fine for thousands of requests in a row, sometimes it occurs after a few hundred.
Any idea why that might occur? I've looked for answers, but found none that were relevant.

Note: I realise that I do not provide a reproducible example, but I can't.
I can't even reproduce the issue myself, since it occurs intermittently.

Comment: Why not include a `try-except` block that will save/print the faulty JSON object?

Comment: Same request doesn't mean same answer. You should write code that logs the returned unprocessed content (at least if the error occurs).

Comment: perhaps some of the requests do not return what you think they do, consider saving one of these faulty response objects and observing what the difference is between that and your desired response

Comment: @all: yes, I should do that. Not sure why I didn't think about it. I do have a try-except, but it retries the request rather than print out the fawlty JSON object.

Answer (score 1):

You can add some error checking to find out why the returned data is not formatted as you expected:

```
r = requests.post(url=url, json=json, headers=headers)
try:
    data = r.json()
    foo = data["foo"]
except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
    print('response was not a JSON string, but', r.text) 
except KeyError:
    print('data does not contain "foo", but', data)
else:
    try:
        bar = foo["bar"]
    except KeyError:
        print('foo does not contain "bar", but', foo)
    except TypeError:
        print('foo is not a dictionary, but', foo)
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not necessarily mean that r.json() is not a valid JSON. It can be a JSON that looks like this:

```
{
  "foo": "randomstring"
}
```

When running `r.json()["foo"]["bar"]` it will throw an exception because `r.json()["foo"]` is actually a string and you need an integer to access one of its elements. You'd pretty much get an exception if it were anything *except* a dictionary.

A quick "fix" to this would be to rewrite `r.json()["foo"]["bar"]` as `r.json().get("foo", {}).get("bar", None)`. This way, if the JSON does not have "foo" or the "foo" dictionary does not have "bar", the value returned will be `None` instead of an Exception.

Comment: Not a list, a string, as the error says  "**String** Indices must be Integers". So it would look like `{"foo": "baz"}`.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question since this won't help OP identify what is wrong but simply ignore the errors

Comment: I know that it doesn't help him figure out his solution, but I hope it offers a solution of what might cause the issue. It's up to OP to do further investigation, imo.

Comment: I know this could be the case, but the same request would presumably always return a JSON object that contains a string rather than a dict in that case. (unless the queried item was removed/modified - but not the case here, I checked)

Comment: Most services have different responses for succes and fail scenarios. Could this be the case?